# How do you take multiple user inputs of different data types within a for loop in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop, java.util.scanner, user-input

I'm trying to prompt the user to type in a string, which will be stored in an array of strings, followed by an inputted int which will be placed into an int array.

I'm running into a problem where the first line is printed, but the user isn't prompted to type in a string. Then the second print statement is immediately printed, and the user is only able to type in an int.

So far I have:

```
    int i, n = 10;
    String[] sentence = new String[1000];
    int[] numbers = new int[1000];



    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
        System.out.println("Enter String" + (i + 1) + ":");
        sentence[i] = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.printf("Enter int " + (i + 1) + ":");
        numbers[i] = scan.nextInt();
        }
```

As output I get:

```
Enter String 1:
Enter int 1:
```

Here you can input an int, and it is stored into the int array. But you can't input a String for the String array.

Ples help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Answer (score 2):

This problem is caused because of `nextInt()` method.

Whats happening here is that `nextInt()` method consumes the integer entered by the user but not the new line character at the end of the user input which is created when you press <kbd>enter</kbd> key.

So when you press <kbd>enter</kbd> after inputting an integer, next call to `nextLine()` consumes the new line character which wasn't consumed in the last iteration of the loop by `nextInt()` method. That's why it skips the input of `String` in the next iteration of the loop and does't waits for the user to input a `String`

**Solution**

You can consume the new line character by calling `nextLine()` after the `nextInt()` call

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    System.out.println("Enter String" + (i + 1) + ":");
    sentence[i] = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.printf("Enter int " + (i + 1) + ":");
    numbers[i] = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();             // <------ this call will consume the new line character
}
```

Comment: The scan.nextLine(); apparently needs to be after the first print statement and before the sentence[i] statement in order to read the very first instance as well. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Anon it will work if you put it at the end of the `for loop` or after the first `System.out.println` statement, just know that you need to consume the new line character after  `nextInt()` method call.

Answer (score 0):

Put scan.nextLine() like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    System.out.println("Enter String" + (i + 1) + ":");
    sentence[i] = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.printf("Enter int " + (i + 1) + ":");
    numbers[i] = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sc.next(); instead of sc.nextLine(); if not able to enter string value in first iteration.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

for(i = 0; i < n; i++);
    System.out.println("Enter String" + (i + 1) + ":");
    sentence[i] = sc.next();

    System.out.printf("Enter int " + (i + 1) + ":");
    numbers[i] = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
}
```